# Requested runtime (ÿþpython-3.6.5) is not available for this stack on Heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I updated the python version from 3.6.4 to 3.6.5 today. This is because, in the process of distributing to Heroku, it recommends version 3.6.5. Therefore, the following power shell contents were confirmed.

```
Writing objects: 100% (35/35), 11.68 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 35 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.5 (you are using ÿþpython-3.6.5, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.5).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing ÿþpython-3.6.5
remote:  !     Requested runtime (ÿþpython-3.6.5) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to XXXXXXXX.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/XXXXXXXX.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/XXXXXXXX.git
```

After changing my `runtime.txt` file to UTF-8, I now get the following error:

```
Writing objects: 100% (35/35), 11.68 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 35 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.5 (you are using python-3.6.5, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.5).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.5
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-3.6.5) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to XXXXXXXX.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/XXXXXXXX.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/XXXXXXXX.git
```

Why is `python-3.6.5` being rejected? Isn't that exactly what Heroku says is the default version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku believes that your `runtime.txt` contains some extra characters:

```
ÿþpython-3.6.5
```

This is probably [byte-order mark for a file encoded as UTF-16 in little-endian order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16). Make sure you're using a sane encoding for that file (and others). UTF-8 is a good choice in virtually all situations.

Comment: Thank you Chris! Well, now the shell is well recognized as python, but the same problem is repeated. `the latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.5, which is unsupported.`

Comment: @Boosil-guy, it's not clear what the problem is now but I still suspect an issue with your `runtime.txt` file. You're definitely using UTF-8 now? What kind of line endings (Windows or Unix)?

Comment: Thank you for always trying! Based on your advice I was able to use UTF-8 to push, but I could see the above error. Also my os is the window.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to install `ÿþpython-3.6.5` not `python-3.6.5` as the console output suggests. Remove `ÿþ` and it should work as expected.

Comment: I just got python 3.6.5 from python. Is þpython-3.6.5 something different from Python?

Comment: `þpython-3.6.5` isn't a thing, as far as I know. As Chris mentioned, remove those extra character(s) and it should work as expected.

Comment: I just typed 'python-3.6.5'. There are no special characters.